# Could this discrete logarithm problem be proved?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Given some values $X$, $Y$, $A$, $B$ and $p$, is there a way to show that there exists (or doesn't exist) an $n$ such that $X = A^n \mod{p}$ and $Y = B^n \mod{p}$? Alternatively, are there particular conditions for $X$ and $Y$ to satisfy in order for such an $n$ to exist or not exist?

Thanks

Comment: There's no reason to copy-and-paste the problem into two copies of the same problem. Your *real* problem is determining when $X$ is a power of $A$ mod $p$. This is true if and only if the multiplicative order of $X$ divides the multiplicative order of $A$, if you're interested.

Comment: @anon What do you mean by copy-and-paste the problem into two copies?

Comment: Your first problem is determining if $X$ is a power of $A$. Your second problem is literally the same exact problem but with potentially different values of $X$ and $A$. There's no reason to have two copies of the same problem!

Comment: @anon Could you please explain why $X$ is a power of $A \mod{p}$ if and only if the ord of $X$ (mod p?) divides the ord of $Y$ (mod p?)?